# Configuring WSO2 BPS 3.2.0 and ESB 4.8.1 through FeatureManager

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to configure BPS 3.2.0 and ESB 4.8.1 through Feature Manager but so far its all without any luck. Here are the steps that i have followed

```
1. Download Latest BPS 3.2.0 , extract and launch the server.
2. Using Feature Manager, i used the Carbon 4.2.0 repo from 
           http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.2.0/
3. From the repo, i selected the Enterprise Service Bus (4.8.1) and installed the featured.
4. Restart the Server.
```

At this point i received the following error in the console-log

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\WSO2CE~1.0\bin\..
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,457]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,461]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 7 6.1, amd64
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,462]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,462]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_51
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,462]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03,Oracle Corporation
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,463]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : D:\WSO2CE~1.0\bin\..
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,463]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : D:\WSO2CE~1.0\bin\..\tmp
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,463]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : saad, en-US, Asia/Karachi
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,616]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,724]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
[2014-08-20 18:26:58,745]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2014-08-20 18:27:01,022]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 80ms
[2014-08-20 18:27:01,226]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2014-08-20 18:27:01,724]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.server.internal.AttachmentServiceComponent} -  Initialising Attachment Server
[2014-08-20 18:27:02,886]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.core.dao.impl.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [Attachment-Mgt OpenJPA] DB Dictionary: h2
[2014-08-20 18:27:02,887]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.core.dao.impl.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [Attachment-Mgt OpenJPA] Generate DDL Enabled.
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,057]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.server.internal.AttachmentServiceComponent} -  Registering AttachmentServerService
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,465]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.internal.BPELServiceComponent} -  Initializing BPEL Engine........
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,533]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Using DAO Connection Factory class: org.apache.ode.dao.jpa.BPELDAOConnectionFactoryImpl
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,916]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering E4X Extension...
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,919]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering B4P Extension...
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,923]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering B4P Filter...
[2014-08-20 18:27:03,933]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering MBeans
[2014-08-20 18:27:04,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Initialising HumanTask Server
[2014-08-20 18:27:04,069]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [HT OpenJPA] DB Dictionary: h2
[2014-08-20 18:27:04,069]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [HT OpenJPA] Generate DDL Enabled.
[2014-08-20 18:27:04,105]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Registering Axis2ConfigurationContextObserver
[2014-08-20 18:27:04,112]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Registering HumanTaskUIResourceProvider
[2014-08-20 18:27:04,623]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2014-08-20 18:27:11,756]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2014-08-20 18:27:13,693]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer} -  Initializing BPEL Deployer for tenant -1234.
[2014-08-20 18:27:13,755]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer.LandingPageWebappDeployer} -  Deployed product landing page webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/home]
[2014-08-20 18:27:13,757]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2014-08-20 18:27:13,757]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.deployer.HumanTaskDeployer} -  Initializing HumanTask Deployer for tenant -1234.
[2014-08-20 18:27:13,920]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2014-08-20 18:27:14,649]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2014-08-20 18:27:15,027]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2014-08-20 18:27:15,381]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2014-08-20 18:27:19,282]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,107]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Repository       : D:\WSO2CE~1.0\bin\../repository/deployment/server/
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,379]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,467]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Starting ESB...
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,480]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,487] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Couldn't initialize the ESB...
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The synapse.xml location .\.\
        ./repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs
    \default doesn't exist
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.handleFatal(SynapseControllerFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.validatePath(SynapseControllerFactory.java:113)
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.validate(SynapseControllerFactory.java:88)
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.createSynapseController(SynapseControllerFactory.java:44)
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:182)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerHandler.startEventBroker(EventBrokerHandler.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerBuilderDS.activate(EventBrokerBuilderDS.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,517]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.rule.kernel.internal.ds.RuleEngineConfigDS} -  Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[2014-08-20 18:27:20,659]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.StatisticsServiceComponent} -  BAM Service Stat Publishing is disabled
[2014-08-20 18:27:22,034]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://192.175.0.116:9443/carbon/
[2014-08-20 18:28:20,370]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:29:20,369]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:30:20,368]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:31:20,369]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:32:20,368]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:33:20,369]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:34:20,368]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
[2014-08-20 18:35:20,368]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
```

I have tried this configuration by starting with the ESB 4.8.1 Installation and then installing BPS 3.2.0 through Feature Manager and with the almost same result. Any ideas how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing BPS features on ESB or vice versa is not recommended. Why is that ?

- Generally ESB is a stateless runtime and BPS is a stateful runtime.
- ESB use for short live synchronous invocation, while BPS uses for long running, asynchronous processes.
- The performance characteristics are also very different between ESB and BPS. ESB uses nio/passthru transport for high performance, But those transport are not supported by the BPS runtime. BPS use servlet transport.

So better to separate them and run ESB and BPS in two different in JVM.